# Do/while loop not counting number of rolls or lining up with dice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just learning javascript and my project is to create a web page with the following elements: An h2 header, two img elements, an input box, and a button element. When the page loads, Dice.getURL is called twice to get the URL for the 1-dot die, and the jQuery.attr() function is used to display the images when the page loads: When the user enters a target number and clicks Roll 'em!, the images are updated die-namically and the results displayed in a div on the page.
I've got the basics down but I have no idea how to do the rest of this stuff. I've been looking online but haven't found what I needed. I hope you guys can be what I need:

The main issue that I have is that the numRolls variable is not keep track of how many times the do/while loop runs through. I am also confused on how to keep track of the dice rolls via images so it displays the correct output when the "solution is found"

Here is a link to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0088v6nt/3/

HTML

```
<!Doctype html>
<body>
    <h2>Roll Number</h2>
    <img id="dice1" src="http://www.dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/die1.gif">
    <img id="dice2" src="http://www.dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/die1.gif">
    <p>Enter target number:</p>
    <input type="text" id="num"><br><br>
    <button id="R">Roll 'em!</button>
    <br><br>
    <div id="time"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
//define a Dice object, properties and methods
var Dice = {
sides: 6,

rollDie: function(diceElement) {
    var rolledValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
    var diceImage = this.getURL(rolledValue);
    diceElement.attr("src", diceImage);
},

rollDice: function() {
   var diceTotal = 0;
   diceTotal += this.rollDie($('#dice1'));
   diceTotal += this.rollDie($('#dice2'));
   return diceTotal;
},

URL_prefix: "http://dave-reed.com/book3e/Images/",

getURL: function(n) {
    //return the URL for an n-dot die
    return this.URL_prefix + "die" + n + ".gif";
}
};

//top-level function
function roll_number(n) {
Dice.rollDice();
var die1 = 0;
var die2 = 0;
var numRolls = 0;
    do {
        die1 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice1'));
        die2 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice2'));
        numRolls++;
    } while(die1 + die2 == n);
    return numRolls;
//roll two dice until you hit n
//return the number of rolls
}

function getRoll () {
 var number = parseFloat($("#num").val());
 var numRolls = roll_number(number);
 $("#time").text( "You rolled " + number + " in " + numRolls + " rolls");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#R").on("click", getRoll);
  //$("#roll").on("click", Dice.getURL);
 });
```

Thank you again!

-Kron

Comment: while loops are generally bad practice in most languages because of their propensity to cause infinite loop bugs.

Comment: die1 and die2 are undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two issues with your code. First die1 and die2 are never set because  `Dice.rollDie` doesn't return a value. Updating the function to return the value of the die fixes this:

```
rollDie: function(diceElement) {
  var rolledValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
  var diceImage = this.getURL(rolledValue);
  diceElement.attr("src", diceImage);
  return rolledValue;
},
```

Second, the while loop currently only set to keep running while the sum matches the total, instead it should keep running while it doesn't match the total. It should look like instead:

```
while(die1 + die2 !== n);
```

This can lead to infinite loops if you pass a bad value to `n` (such as null, or anything greater than 12), so be careful

https://jsfiddle.net/0088v6nt/4/

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the counter to zero every time the `roll_number` function is called i fixed it by moving the counter variable outside the function scope so it's not being reset all the time..

```
var numRolls = 0;
function roll_number(n) {
    Dice.rollDice();
    var die1 = 0;
    var die2 = 0;
        do {
            die1 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice1'));
            die2 = Dice.rollDie($('#dice2'));
            numRolls++;
        } while(die1 + die2 == n);
        return numRolls;
    //roll two dice until you hit n
    //return the number of rolls
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0088v6nt/5/